# AJAX is sending all null data to the Spring Controller using POST mapping?

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to send data from HTML Form with POST mapping using ajax to the spring controller. But it's sending all null data. Tried lots of variation for ajax. It's sending the school object but all fields are null. The console shows the fields are saving but all becomes null in the AJAX.

Here is the createSchoolForm.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Create School || EDUBD</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>EDUBD - Manage School Portal</h1>

    <h3>Create New School</h3> <br>

    <form id="createSchool">
        <br>
        <label>School Name:
        <input type="text" id="schoolName"  value="" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>School Email:
        <input type="text" id="schoolEmail" value="" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>School Phone Number:
        <input type="tel" id="schoolPhone" value="" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <div id="feedback"></div>



    <script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $("#createSchool").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var schoolData = {
                    schoolName: $("#schoolName").val(),
                    schoolEmail: $("#schoolEmail").val(),
                    schoolPhone: $("#schoolPhone").val(),
                    status: null,
                    schoolStreet: null,
                    schoolHouse: null,
                    schoolZip: null,
                    schoolCity: null,
                    schoolState: null,
                    schoolCountry: null,
                    image: null,
                    createBy: null,
                    updatedBy: null,
                    createdDate: null,
                    updatedDate: null,
                    id: null
                };
               // let j = JSON.stringify(schoolData);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(schoolData));

                $.ajax({
                    header:{
                        contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                    },
                    type : "post",
                    url : "Create",
                    data : JSON.stringify(schoolData),
                    dataType : "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4>&lt;pre&gt;"
                            + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + "&lt;/pre&gt;";
                        $('#feedback').html(json);
                        console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4>&lt;pre&gt;"
                            + e.responseText + "&lt;/pre&gt;";
                        $('#feedback').html(json);
                        console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create School")
    //@PostMapping(BASE_SCHOOL_PATH+"/Create")
    @PostMapping(value = BASE_SCHOOL_PATH+"/Create", produces = {"application/json"},
            consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    public  String create (School school, @ApiIgnore HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // components tests are expecting this assertion and exception handling, and will fail if removed
        try {
            Assert.isNull(school.getId(), "School ID field must be null");
            Assert.notNull(school.getSchoolEmail(),"School email cannot be null.");
            Assert.notNull(school.getSchoolPhone(),"School Phone number cannot be null. ");
            Assert.isNull(schoolDao.readByEmail(school.getSchoolEmail()),"School already exists in the system.");
            schoolDao.create(school, null);
            return "createSchoolForm";
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this question about javascript or java? They are two completely different languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Solution that worked for me.**

I have tried different ways to solve the problem. It actually helped me to understand how HTTP request works. Here is the solution that worked for me.
I used XMLHttpRequest() to send the data from the HTML form. After sending, I had to capture the data with `@RequestBody`. This is important for the POST to work.
I also had 2 different `produces` and `consumes` in my controller. Had to match those. Lastly, used `<button>` in place of `<input>` for the submission.

**The Solution**

New HTML looks like this:

```
 <h3>Create New School</h3> <br>
    <form id="createSchool" method="post">
        <br>
        <label>School Name:
        <input type="text" id="schoolName"  value="" required/>
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>School Email:
        <input type="email" id="schoolEmail" value="" required/>
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>School Phone Number:
        <input type="tel" id="schoolPhone" value="" required/>
        </label>
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </form>

    <div id="feedback"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $("#submit").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var school=new Object(); //creating object to add values. 
                school.schoolName = $("#schoolName").val();
                school.schoolEmail= $("#schoolEmail").val();
                school.schoolPhone = $("#schoolPhone").val();
                school.status= null;
                school.schoolStreet= null;
                school.schoolHouse= null;
                school.schoolZip= null;
                school.schoolCity= null;
                school.schoolState= null;
                school.schoolCountry= null;
                school.image= null;
                school.createBy= null;
                school.updatedBy= null;
                school.createdDate= null;
                school.updatedDate= null;
                school.id= null;

                var s2=JSON.stringify(school);
                console.log(s2);

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "SchoolCreate",true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
                    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
                        // Request finished. Do processing here.
                        console.log("success");
                        $('#feedback').html("Success");
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        $('#feedback').html(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }
                xhr.send(s2);

                //This will empty the fields after submission.
                document.getElementById('schoolName').value='';
                document.getElementById('schoolEmail').value='';
                document.getElementById('schoolPhone').value='';


            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

The Controller:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create School")
    @PostMapping(value = "/ManageSchool"+BASE_SCHOOL_PATH+"/SchoolCreate", produces = {"application/json"},
            consumes = {"application/json"})
    public String create (@RequestBody School school, @ApiIgnore HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // components tests are expecting this assertion and exception handling, and will fail if removed
        try {
            Assert.isNull(school.getId(), "School ID field must be null");
            Assert.notNull(school.getSchoolEmail(),"School email cannot be null.");
            Assert.notNull(school.getSchoolPhone(),"School Phone number cannot be null. ");
            Assert.isNull(schoolDao.readByEmail(school.getSchoolEmail()),"School already exists in the system.");
            schoolDao.create(school, null);
            return "createSchoolForm";
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

These answers helped me to find some ground in the end.

[How to transfer data from HTML to controller Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514945/how-to-transfer-data-from-html-to-controller-spring)

[XMLHttpRequest not sending POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217910/xmlhttprequest-not-sending-post-data)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ajax function, Try sending the data as form data:

First, create a form data object by using the HTML Form:

```
let createSchoolForm = document.getElementById('createSchool');
let formData = new FormData(createSchoolForm );
```

Then, add it to the `data` key in the Ajax object. Remove the `header` and `dataType` as it may conflict with the Ajax communication.

```
 $.ajax({
                    type : "post",
                    url : "Create",
                    data : formData
                    success: function (data) {
                        var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4>&lt;pre&gt;"
                            + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + "&lt;/pre&gt;";
                        $('#feedback').html(json);
                        console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4>&lt;pre&gt;"
                            + e.responseText + "&lt;/pre&gt;";
                        $('#feedback').html(json);
                        console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                    }
                });
```

Full Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Create School || EDUBD</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>EDUBD - Manage School Portal</h1>

    <h3>Create New School</h3> <br>

    <form id="createSchool">
        <br>
        <label>School Name:
        <input type="text" id="schoolName"  value="" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>School Email:
        <input type="text" id="schoolEmail" value="" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>School Phone Number:
        <input type="tel" id="schoolPhone" value="" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <div id="feedback"></div>



    <script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $("#createSchool").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var schoolData = {
                    schoolName: $("#schoolName").val(),
                    schoolEmail: $("#schoolEmail").val(),
                    schoolPhone: $("#schoolPhone").val(),
                    status: null,
                    schoolStreet: null,
                    schoolHouse: null,
                    schoolZip: null,
                    schoolCity: null,
                    schoolState: null,
                    schoolCountry: null,
                    image: null,
                    createBy: null,
                    updatedBy: null,
                    createdDate: null,
                    updatedDate: null,
                    id: null
                };
               // let j = JSON.stringify(schoolData);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(schoolData));

               let createSchoolForm = document.getElementById('createSchool');
               let formData = new FormData(createSchoolForm );

                $.ajax({
                    type : "post",
                    url : "Create",
                    data : formData 
                    success: function (data) {
                        var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4>&lt;pre&gt;"
                            + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + "&lt;/pre&gt;";
                        $('#feedback').html(json);
                        console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4>&lt;pre&gt;"
                            + e.responseText + "&lt;/pre&gt;";
                        $('#feedback').html(json);
                        console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried that. Now, it's not going to the controller. It's giving error. Here is the error from browser console. 

`{"schoolName":"UWM",.....,....}
jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
at e (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4)
at dc (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4)
at Function.n.param (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4)
at Function.ajax (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (SchoolCreate:63)
at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:3)
at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:3)`